# Using a 2d array to display coordinates on a Map/Grid

Tags: c++, dictionary, grid, char, multidimensional-array

I am trying to place a crop on a map/grid. The crop is a string of characters that need to display in the maps borders. I need to use a 2d array to display the individual characters that will form a crop shape on the map. This is the code I have so far but it isn't giving me the right shapes for the crop when they are displayed.

```
bool Crop::place(char map[MAPL][MAPW],int x_crop,int y_crop)const{

cout << '\n';
cout << setw(24) << right << "11111111112\n";
cout << setw(24) << right << "12345678901234567890\n";
cout << "  " << setw(21) << setfill('-') << left << '+' << right << '+' << setfill (' ') <<     endl;



for(int x=0; x < MAPW;x++){
    cout << setw(2) << right << x+1 << "|";
    for(int y=0; y < MAPL;y++){
        cout << map[x][y];

    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
}

cout << "  " << setw(21) << setfill('-') << left << '+' << right << '+' << setfill (' ') << endl;
cout << setw(24) << right << "11111111112\n";
cout << setw(24) << right << "12345678901234567890\n";

return true;
}
```

Here is a sample of what the output should look like. It has two crops, "c" and "p" on the map which is 20 width by 10 height

```
            11111111112
   12345678901234567890
  +--------------------+
 1|                    |
 2|                    |
 3|    cc              |
 4|    cc              |
 5|    cc              |
 6|    cc              |
 7|           pppppppp |
 8|           pppppppp |
 9|           pppppppp |
10|                    |
 +--------------------+
            11111111112
   12345678901234567890
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you have is a sideways error.  In the loop:

```
for(int x=0; x < MAPW;x++){
    cout << setw(2) << right << x+1 << "|";
    for(int y=0; y < MAPL;y++){
        cout << map[x][y];
    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
```

You are printing one column at a time instead of one row at a time (column-major order), so it's printing your field sideways.  If you switch MAPW and MAPL (and switch x and y to make the variables descriptive of this change), doing

```
for(int y=0; y < MAPL;y++){
    cout << setw(2) << right << y+1 << "|";
    for(int x=0; x < MAPW;x++){
        cout << map[y][x];
    }
    cout << "|" << endl;
}
```

you will be printing one row at a time (row-major order) and will print out every space in the field.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but what happened when I used that was the array was too small and the array grabbed garbage characters after its max value was gone over. What I mean by that is the map has to be 10 height and 20 width so if I reverse them the height goes over 10 to 20 and gets random values instead of the character in the array.

Comment: Did you switch MAPL and MAPW everywhere in the code or just in the loop?  I only switched them in the loop and that worked for me.  Basically what you have to do is make it so the outer loop iterates MAPL times (the number of rows in the map) and the inner loop iterates MAPW times (the number of spaces in a row).

Comment: I only switched them in the loop as well, but maybe its because the values for MAPL & MAPW are defined in a header file named map.h

Comment: Do you have 10 for MAPL and 20 for MAPW?

Comment: No I have `const int MAPL=20;` `const int MAPW=10;` but if I switch these values around that will change the size of my map, I need it to still be 20 width and 10 height.

Comment: From the names MAPW and MAPL, wouldn't MAPW be the width?  Based on the way the rest of the code in that function behaves, it is treating MAPW as the width and MAPL as the height, so I think those constants are switched.

Comment: you were right all along, thanks a lot for the help!